# Angular 6 setTimeout

Tags: angular, typescript-typings

I know there were some intricacies with timeouts in AngularJS, and was wondering how it works in Angular (latest).
Looking at the definitions set in index.d.ts, I see the following definition:

```
declare function setTimeout(callback: (...args: any[]) => void, ms: number, ...args: any[]): NodeJS.Timer;
```

So, I thought that I'm using the setTimeout function from [Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/), but when I checked the compiled code, there's no mentioning of the NodeJS.Timer, and setTimeout remains unchanged.

So, I guess it turns into window.setTimeout on compile? Did anyone run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition is made for the developper, not for the final product : in Javascript, variables aren't typed, and don't implement interfaces (or aren't instance of classes).

This means that somewhere in your definitions, you will a `NodeJS.Timer` interface, that will give you all the properties of that interface. But it could have been called `HeyDude.WhereIs.MyCar`, this wouldn't have made a difference.

Bottom line is, don't bother with that, that's just code completion. If you have another question, feel free to ask it in your question.

Comment: thanks, that makes sense. Still a bit strange, I could use a property that happily exists in my ts code, but will cease to exist in my compiled code. I guess that's something developer should take care of...

Comment: What is that property ?

Comment: I mean theoretically. A snippet from NodeJS timers docs: "Timers integrate very closely with the system, and despite the fact that the API mirrors the browser API, there are some differences in implementation."

Comment: Well I don't know enough to answer that, so I'll trust your theory on this one !